# Iterate list and show only items which contains specific word

Tags: c#

I would like to iterate a list and show only items which contain a specific word. For example, I have `List<string> {"one","two",three",four","one"}`. I would like to show only: `"one, one"`.

Here's what I have:

```
string strnumbers = "";
foreach (var v in numbers)
{

        strnumbers += v + ",";

}
```

Comment: Why are you using semicolon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using LINQ `Where` and `string.Join`:

```
string strnumbers = string.Join(", ", numbers.Where(number => number == "one"));
```

Comment: `number.Contains("one")` might meet the OP requirements more than `number == "one"`, as he wants strings which "contain" a specific word.

Comment: @Youssef13 Maybe, but the example would suggest OP wants equals.

Comment: @Youssef13 You should use a comment on the question to ask for clarification of that.

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting to do this with multiple words, it might be worth using `GroupBy`:

```
var list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "one", "two" };

var groups = list
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => string.Join(", ", grp));

Console.WriteLine(groups["one"]);
// one, one

Console.WriteLine(groups["two"]);
// two, two
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna leave this here as an alternative for @Johnathan barcley s notation that also highlights ignore casing.

```
var source = new string[] {"one","two","three","four","one"};

var filtered = from number in numbers
               where number.Contains("one", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               select number

string result = string.Join(",", filtered);
```